# What is the condition of invertibility of $ \left( {I + {F^{ - 1}}\Delta F} \right) $?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose ${\left( {F + \Delta F} \right)^{ - 1}} = {\left( {I + {F^{ - 1}}\Delta F} \right)^{ - 1}}{F^{ - 1}}$. Why the condition for invertibility of $ \left( {I + {F^{ - 1}}\Delta F} \right) $ is 
$\left\| {{F^{ - 1}}\Delta F} \right\| < 1$?

Comment: It is well known that if $\|M\| < 1$, then the matrix $I + M$ is invertible.  Note that this is a sufficient, but not necessary, condition for the invertibility of $I + M$.

Comment: Could you prove the condition that you come up?

Comment: Is it true for all matrix norms?

Comment: It is indeed true for all matrix norms (i.e. all submultiplicative norms).  And sure, I'll write up the proof below.

Comment: Thank you for introducing the references and your proofs. Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 0):

> **Theorem:** Let $\|\cdot\|$ be a submultiplicative matrix norm (i.e. it holds that $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\,\|B\|$ for all relevant matrices $A,B$).  If $M$ is square with $\|M\| < 1$, then $I + M$ is invertible.

For a reference, I'd recommend Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*, whose chapter on matrix norms covers this and more.

There are two common proofs of this fact.

**Proof 1:** We begin with the observation that $\rho(M) < \|M\|$ (where $\rho(M)$ is the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $M$).  Since every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M$ satisfies $|\lambda| < 1$, the eigenvalues of $M + I$ will satisfy (by the reverse triangle inequality)
$$
|1 + \lambda| \geq |1 - |\lambda|| > 0
$$
Since none of the eigenvalues of $M + I$ are zero, $M + I$ must be invertible.

**Proof 2:** We can use the [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).  In particular, we note that if the series $S = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-M)^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k M^k$ converges, then we must have $SM = MS = I$, which is to say that $S = M^{-1}$.  To see that the series converges, it suffices to note that
$$
\|S\| = \left\|\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k M^k\right\| \leq \sum_{k=0}^\infty \|M\|^k = \frac{1}{1 - \|M\|} < \infty
$$
Notably, this proof extends to infinite-dimensional contexts (i.e. to bounded operators over Banach spaces and Banach algebras).

Answer (score 0):

Can we prove it by contraposition?
If $I + M$ is singular then $\left\| M \right\| \geqslant 1$?
If $I + M$ is singular there exist an $x$ in the null space of $I + M$ so one can write $(I + M)x=0$.
Hence, $x=-Mx$ and by taking norm of both sides (by assuming that the norm is submultiplicative matrix norm) 
$\left\| x \right\| = \left\| {Mx} \right\| \leqslant \left\| M \right\|\left\| x \right\| \Rightarrow \left\| M \right\| \geqslant 1$

Comment: Yes, this proof is correct.  I would think of this as another version of my first proof: if $I + M$ is singular, then $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, which means that $\|M\| \geq |-1| = 1$.